# admin_order_field not ordering in descending order

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Am trying to order items in the column in descending order, but it's not working , below is my model :

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    count_num = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Then, in the `admin.py` file I have this :

```
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'color_code', 'counting')


    def counting(self, obj):
        return obj.count_num
    counting.admin_order_field = '-count_num'
```

But the column **counting** seems not to be sorted , below is the screenshot :

[image]

Comment: In the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/) they create a method in model class and the `admin_order_field` is added there, not in `ModelAdmin` class, can you check it?

Comment: I did that but it was the same results @PawełKordowski

Answer (score 0):

Try this is **admin.py**:

```
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['-count_num']
    list_display = ('first_name', 'color_code', 'count_num')
```

Make sure your `url` has not been already sorted..

For Ex.

Real : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blaa/` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blaa/?o=2` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blaa/?o=5.2`